# How to always select a specific row from MySQL table and show on android TextView with retrofit

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, retrofit

I am trying to retrieve mySQL data using retrofit.

With the php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","PW","testing");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_table");



echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>y1</th>
<th>y2</th>
<th>timestamps</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['y1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['y2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['timestamps'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have created the following table:

```
y1  y2  timestamps
25  70  2021-1-14 17:10:00
12  69  2021-1-14 17:30:02
15  55  2021-1-14 17:50:00
```

The data will be keep adding into y1, y2, and timestamps (ie. more rows will be added after 15/55).

I am using retrofit to hope to display the latest row (whenever the new row is being inserted into the table) and tried to retrieve them.

I have MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nametxt, agetxt, phonetxt;
    Button retrieveBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nametxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
        agetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agetxt);
        phonetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phonetxt);
        retrieveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieveBtn);

        retrieveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetchData();
            }
        });
    }


    private void fetchData() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<List<Details_Pojo>> call = api.getstatus();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Details_Pojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Details_Pojo>> call, Response<List<Details_Pojo>> response) {
                List<Details_Pojo> adslist = response.body();

                String name = adslist.get(0).getName();
                String age = adslist.get(0).getAge();
                String phone = adslist.get(0).getPhone();

                nametxt.setText(name);
                agetxt.setText(age);
                phonetxt.setText(phone);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Details_Pojo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

POJO:

```
public class Details_Pojo {
    @SerializedName("y1")
    @Expose
    private String Name;
    @SerializedName("y2")
    @Expose
    private String Age;
    @SerializedName("timestamps")
    @Expose
    private String Phone;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Api:

```
public interface Api {


    String BASE_URL = "xxx";   //http
    @GET("Api.php")

    Call<List<Details_Pojo>> getstatus();

}
```

I am using the  the JSON array method (POJO) to display the latest data row into the TextView on Android but the data is not being retrieved. The app is running but with no errors. Could someone have inside on displaying the latest row of MySql data table on Android TextView (only retrieving the last y1 y2 timestamps row even if the new data is being inserted)?

**Updates** It worked with JSON format but wondering whether table format would also worked or whether it needs to be convert to JSON

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use json_encode to push the data into json and parse with rf2 gson

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would it work with tables? Or do I have to use json_encode to make it JSON??